# Is it problematic for a React hook to return an object with chained methods?

Tags: react-hooks, tanstackreact-query

**TL;DR;** Totally contrived example. Is there anything wrong with doing this?

```js
const useHookWithChainedMethods = () => {
  const _internal = { foo: 'FOO' };

  const self = {
    getFoo: () => _internal.foo,
    setFoo: (foo) => {
      _internal.foo = foo;
      return self;
    }
  }

  return self;
}


const MyComponent = () => {
  const foo = useHookWithChainedMethods()
    .setFoo('BAR')
    .getFoo();
}
```

The real code involves [@tanstack/query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest). We have an API endpoint that allows resource join logic by building up a rather verbose "query" object. I introduced a `buildQuery` util to make this easier using chained methods.

```js
const fooWithBarQuery = buildQuery('Foo')
  .addJoin('Bar', { localKey: 'barId', targetKey: 'fooId' })
  .useBuiltQuery(); // Returns a standard @tanstack/query QueryResponse
```

This *was* a pure function. I now want to add a method to invalidate the built query, which requires a reference to the query client via `useQueryClient()`. From there, the rules of hooks dictate that `buildQuery` becomes a hook itself —`useQueryBuilder`. But I still want to keep the chained method API.

This all seems to work without issue. But I have concerns. Primarily that only the initial `useQueryBuilder` call will receive whatever special "hook" handling React provides, & calls to chained methods will somehow be processed outside of the standard hook lifecycle.